# Переведите пожалуйста с языка C++ на C и если есть ошибки исправьте пожалуйста

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
    float a, b, x;
    cin>>a>>b;
    x = (0 - b)/a;
    if (a == 0 && b == 0) count <<"Any";
    else  if (a == 0) count<<"No answer";
    else count<<x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Перевести-то нетрудно, но почему бы вам не сделать такую простую задачку самому? `cin >>` - см. `scanf`, `cout <<` (не `count`!!!) - см. `printf`... Ерунда в проверках `a` на равенство нулю - как же вы перед этим на ноль делили? Проверку надо выполнять сначала, а уже потом, перед выводом `x`, вычислять его значение - когда вы знаете, что вычислять можно...

Comment: Проверка на `a == 0` делается уже после того, как на `a` выполнено деление...

Comment: Объясните, зачем вы так старательно портите форматирование?!

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что бюро переводов в другом месте...

Comment: @Harry, с Си++ на Си - это что-то новенькое. У меня почти получилось!

Comment: @AnT, пока там типы не целые, не страшно.

Answer (score 5):

Ну почти получилось как хотел: http://ideone.com/wH0b4V

```
typedef double using;
#define namespace namespace,
#include <stdio.h>
#define cin double*p[]={&namespace 0};scanf("%lf %lf", &std, &namespace std)
#define float int
signed count;
#define return return!printf("%f\0Any\0$$No answer"+3*(!std*(1+2*!!**p)),-**p/std),
//\
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
    float a, b, x;
    cin>>a>>b;
    x = (0 - b)/a;
    if (a == 0 && b == 0) count <<'Any';
    else  if (a == 0) count<<'No answer';
    else count<<x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Шикарно :) (10 символов)

Comment: @int3, как-то можно кавычки сохранить?

Comment: Извращенец.(4 символа нужно)